# Force Internet Explorer 9 into Quirks Mode

Tags: css, html, browser

I have a web design class and our teacher wish's for us to force a browser into quirks mode.

Is their any CSS feature or html 5 feature that will do the job? Its for a discussion question but I need to make a simple webpage.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the real value in learning about quirks mode except for curiosity's sake. You will almost definitely never use it in real life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't provide a doctype, it will go into quirks mode on its own.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>I'm in Quirks Mode</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Quirks mode supports the JavaScript functionality of 
        IE6, and the Quirks mode of IE7 and IE8.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you need something to cite:

> If your webpage uses one or more features that require IE9 mode and you do not include a standards-compliant !DOCTYPE directive, Internet Explorer 9 displays, by default, your webpage in IE5 (Quirks) mode, which does not support features that require IE9 mode. [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699338(v=vs.85).aspx)

Additionally you can force it into Quirks Mode via the developer tools as well; just press F12 and change the Document Mode. Note that this method is usually only used for quick testing, and affects your local copy only.

[image]

Comment: nice explanation! My book mentions that method. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Adding any HTML comment block above your  tag will throw IE9 into Quirks Mode!

Like this

```
<!-- -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Source http://timjames.me/force-ie9-into-quirks-mode

Answer (score 1):

try without `doctype` but it wont be a good idea

or try

```
<!-- -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```